# SQL - data from two tables

Tags: sql

I want to make some select of data from two different tables and sum up some values

I have got two tables:

Table **material**:

```
materialID    MaterialName   Maxvalue  
1234            matA          30
4321            matB          20
```

Table **Quantity**:

```
materialID    quantity
1234           20
1234           1
1234           10
4321           5
4321           6
```

There is match between the table `material` and `Quantity` - this match is `materialID`.

What I want is to select the `SUM` quantity of materials that quantity is over the `MAX` value - in this situation the result should be:

```
materialname  sum
matA          31
```

I used some inner `join`, `group by`, `sum` function etc but without success.

Comment: Please tag a specific database.

Comment: What values are you trying to sum ?

Answer (score 1):

You can join and group both tables and then use a having clause to filter the result:

```
select m.materialname, sum(q.quantity) as quantity
from material m 
  join quantity q on m.materialid = q.materialid
group by m.materialname
having sum(q.quantity) >= max(m.maxvalue);
```

The max() in  `>= max(m.maxvalue)` is necessary because it is an un-grouped column (you can't use `having sum(q.quantity) >= m.maxvalue`). But using max() won't change anything, because all values will be the same for the same materialname.

Online example: https://rextester.com/KNL78530

Answer (score 0):

Use join with subquery

```
select m.materialID,MaterialName,Maxvalue
from material m
inner join 
(select materialID,sum(quantity) as qty
from quantity
group by materialID
)q m.materialID=q.materialID
where qty>Maxvalue
```

Comment: You select an unknown column `c`.

Comment: Chose table aliases that make sense, like `m` for `material` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
select materialName, m.maxValue - q.qty
from material m
inner join (
   select materialID, sum(quantity) qty
   from quantity
   group by materialID) q on m.materialID = q.materialID
                             and q.qty > m.maxValue
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a straight forward join and sum:

```
select m.MaterialName, SUM(q.quantity) from #material m 
inner join #quantity q on m.materialID = q.materialID
group by m.MaterialName
```